# Modal WinForms Progress Bar owned by a WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to display a modal WinForms progress bar (child) on top of a WPF window (parent). The modality is achieved by setting the Owner property of child to parent, except that child.Owner has to be of type Form (the progress bar works fine without modality when parent is of type WPF Window). Since parent is of type Window, not Form, I tried using the win32 libs directly to achieve modality. Here is what I have done.

Looking at the source code for the setter for property Owner in Forms.cs, I could see that it calls

```
SetWindowLong(child.Handle, -8, parent.Handle);
```

This call seems to disable interaction with the parent, which is exactly what I want. While I want this to work when parent is a WPF window, I tested this approach with parent being a Forms window first. I noticed two oddities:

1. Setting DialogResult on child no longer closes/hides child. I have to manually call Hide(). Why?
2. After calling Hide(), parent is still completely disabled, i.e. I cannot click any buttons, cannot move the window nor do anything else with it. It is completely frozen. I assume I have to undo the SetWindowLong parent/child relationship somehow but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Can anybody help?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you need the ProgressBar to be what is Modal? Could you simply create a small Form window that contains that ProgressBar and then call ShowDialog on the Form?

Comment: @JeffR Ideally, yes, as the progress bar is in a separate dll. I cannot easily modify the code.